# Connect two environment variable

Tags: bash, unix, debian, export, environment-variables

I've got two environment variables, one is:

```
 export COMMAND='sudo curl https://transfer.sh/n32gU/dockkub -o dockkub && kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address='
```

another is:

```
export EXIP='123.3.765.231'
```

How to connect it to one that looks like this:

```
sudo curl https://transfer.sh/n32gU/dockkub -o dockkub && kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 --apiserver-advertise-address=123.3.765.231
```

And store to EXEC variable

Comment: See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply connect them as could be done with every string in bash:

```
export EXEC="$COMMAND$EXIP"
```

Equivalent alternatives are

```
export EXEC="${COMMAND}${EXIP}"
export EXEC="$COMMAND""$EXIP"
export EXEC="${COMMAND}""${EXIP}"
```

Note that by [convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/673940/6770384) uppercase variables are used by the system. Good practice is to spell your variables in lowercase.

#### Alternative for executing `$EXEC`

It seems like you want to use `$EXEC` as a command. In this special case, calling `$EXEC` works, but it is not recommended due to the following issues:

- Arguments with spaces are not possible.
- Symbols like `*` and `?` will be expanded.

A better way to write and call the command would be a function:

```
myfunction() {
    sudo curl https://transfer.sh/n32gU/dockkub -o dockkub &&
    kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=10.244.0.0/16 \
                 --apiserver-advertise-address="$1"
}
export -f myfunction
```